# Finding the Frechet derivative of $f:\mathbb{R}^{N\times N} \to \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}, X\mapsto X^2$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, frechet-derivative

We just introduced the concept of the Frechet-derivative in class and I'm trying to grasp how to do it so I want to know wether my understanding is correct.

Let's consider $$f:\mathbb{R}^{N\times N} \to \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}, X\mapsto X^2$$

The continous, linear function $T$ is the Frechet derivative of $f$, if
$$f(X+ \epsilon) = f(X) + T\epsilon + r(\epsilon)$$ and
$$\lim_{||\epsilon||\to0}\frac{r(\epsilon)}{||\epsilon||} = 0$$

If I now want to calculate this for $f$, I get
$$f(X + \epsilon) = (X + \epsilon)^2 = X^2 + X\epsilon + \epsilon X + \epsilon^2$$

$\epsilon^2$ satisfies the limit condition, $X^2$ is $f(x)$, so I think that $X\epsilon + \epsilon X$ = Tx

But how can I explictly find this $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ is exactly the linear map $\mathbb R^{N\times N} \to \mathbb R^{N\times N}$ given by

$$T\epsilon = X\epsilon + \epsilon X, \ \ \ \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R^{N\times N}.$$

You cannot be more explicit then that, since $X\in \mathbb R^{N\times N}$ is arbitrary. This is the Frechet-derivative **at** $X$.

Comment: It seems like I misunderstood the notation/Definition then. I understood $T$ as an object being multiplied to $\epsilon$ from the left, but am I understanding you correctly that $T\epsilon$ is just an abreviation for the more explicit $T(\epsilon)$?

Comment: @maibrl That's correct